# How to get rid this purple icon?

Tags: applications, malware

The phone is a samsung 21. When I click on the purple icon or just randomly on its own, this screen pops up. It does not matter how many times I drag the icon to the X to remove it, it comes right back.

[image]How do you get rid of this purple icon that opens up ads every time you touch your phone?

[image]

Comment: I would probably help to known which device model you have and version of OS. Unclear which 'purple icon' you are referring to. If it is the one that looks like the planet Saturn in the center that should be the Samsung Internet app icon. The position is odd so it may be a Samsung customization. See if you can select it an drag it to the bottom / home button there should be a 'X' which will remove it. Alternatively swipe from right or left for a edge menu for possible controls.

Comment: It looks like an app icon that got stuck while trying to move - have you restarted the phone since this occurred?

Comment: Try: Settings->Apps->Samsung Internet->App Info screen, scroll to bottom to the section named "Advanced" and disable "Appears on Top" and disable "Change system settings" and disable "Picture-in-picture". There is a version number at the bottom, please add it to your question. There is a gear icon at the top of the 'App Info', tap and check the home page URL. Try removing the icon from the home screen/problem locations. If still present go back to the same Samsung Internet 'App Info' screen as earlier and click on 'Force Stop' in bottom menu bar. Report back with details.

Comment: @MorrisonChang based on OP's edit, a search for Votiha.com shows it's a [luxury yacht service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxYTm.jpg). I would be tempted to think it's a related app or some ad malware but for the fact that icons are different (Votiha vs Saturn) // Stacey, go through your apps list and uninstall any such app//If you can't find any related app, boot into safe mode(Google how to for your device) and if the icon disappears in safe mode, then it is for sure related to some installed app

Comment: @beeshyams I agree that something is causing the malware but I doubt a lux yacht service is doing it but some other nefarious app. Such an app may however be using Samsung Internet app (seriously that app has a lot of stuff in its setting including ad blocker plugins which may have been hijacked) as the "front face" so locking that one down is difficult without being in person. To be clear I do agree with your suggested actions.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I haven't used a Samsung in ages but you seem to be knowing a lot about them. Probably OP didn't even enable the adb locker plug in (unless it's enabled by default). I appreciate your insights!

Comment: After seeing the latest screenshot, looks like it's Samsung Internet app running in picture-in-picture (PIP) mode, hence the partial window and address bar not shown. Tapping the small gray bar at the top of the window will show a small pop-up to modify the PIP mode, including returning it back to full-screen.